# Nginx redirect setting

Tags: wordpress, nginx

My Nginx setting currently has this:

```
 location / {
       if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://domain.com/index.php?id=$1 redirect;
       }
 }
```

Basically for non-existing pages (404) it redirects user to the home page. But now I have a wordpress blog setup at https://domain.com/blog/, but any wordpress items eg. https://domain.com/blog/test also got redirected to the home page. I wonder how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do something different for requested url's whose path starts with '/blog/' add a corresponding location like so:

```
location / {
   if (!-e $request_filename){ 
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://domain.com/index.php?id=$1 redirect; }
} 


location /blog/ {
    #add in whatever directives are needed to serve your wordpress
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using an `if`. Please read the [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) page on the nginx wiki. Instead you should be using `try_files`.

Your config should look more like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @notfound
}

location @notfound {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/index.php?id=$1 redirect; 
}
```

Really, you shouldn't be doing this at all. Instead you should be setting a [custom error](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page) page. Redirecting every 404 to the home page is bad for your SEO.

Edit: I just realized you were passing the URL into "id". So I removed my second comment about using `.` instead of `^(.*)$`. Still an error page is your best bet. You can pick up the URL with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (if you avoid the hard redirect).

This [page](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration) has some sample configurations that may be helpful to you. It has a few wordpress configs.

Comment: as that `ifIsEvil` page you linked explains, an if with a return or rewrite is non-problematic, so that wasn't the problem (though the try_files is a better approach in general)